# AsyncTask alternative for simple cases

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When I want to do something in background, if the action is very simple: Like do "something in background" and then update the UI, instead of using an `AsyncTask` I'm considering to use (just for faster coding):

```
 new Thread(){
      public void run(){
          final ArrayList<myObjects> objects= myDatabase.queryObjects();
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                updateUIWith(objects);              
            }
        });
      }
 }
```

But I really don't know if using "final" objects that way can result in memory leaks or have other kind of troubles.

Is using this method OK?

Comment: Code is fine. Unless and until you are making sure that you don't change the state of objects reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` only says to the compiler that you won't reallocate the `objects` variable in your code. There is no link between `final` and memory leaks.

If you use an anonymous inner class (the `new Runnable...`) you have to make `objects` final.

I am not very familiar with Android but if your `updateUIWith()` method does interact with UI objects, it might be an issue as I would assume UI updates need to run in a specific UI thread. If you don't update UI objects in that method then you code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Is it a good idea to open a new thread for every little action? AsyncTask provides the convenience of the threads being managed by someone else, but when you declare a thread like you did, you're responsible for dealing with situation such as limitations on the number of threads.